# How to change tooltip content in c3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I'm working on a timeline display and I have data that I want to show on the tooltip. currently it only shows the value at each time. and I cannot find a way to change it. the example below shows how to change the value's format but not what values are displayed

```
var chart = c3.generate({
data: {
    columns: [
        ['data1', 30000, 20000, 10000, 40000, 15000, 250000],
        ['data2', 100, 200, 100, 40, 150, 250]
    ],
    axes: {
        data2: 'y2'
    }
},
axis : {
    y : {
        tick: {
            format: d3.format("s")
        }
    },
    y2: {
        show: true,
        tick: {
            format: d3.format("$")
        }
    }
},
tooltip: {
    format: {
        title: function (d) { return 'Data ' + d; },
        value: function (value, ratio, id) {
            var format = id === 'data1' ? d3.format(',') : d3.format('$');
            return format(value);
        }
           //value: d3.format(',') // apply this format to both y and y2
    }
}
});
```

it's taken from http://c3js.org/samples/tooltip_format.html
they do admit that there isn't an example for content editing but I couldn't find anything in the reference or forums, but a suggestion to change the code (it's here: https://github.com/masayuki0812/c3/blob/master/c3.js in line 300) and below:

```
__tooltip_contents = getConfig(['tooltip', 'contents'], function (d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) {
        var titleFormat = __tooltip_format_title ? __tooltip_format_title : defaultTitleFormat,
            nameFormat = __tooltip_format_name ? __tooltip_format_name : function (name) { return name; },
            valueFormat = __tooltip_format_value ? __tooltip_format_value : defaultValueFormat,
            text, i, title, value, name, bgcolor;
        for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
            if (! (d[i] && (d[i].value || d[i].value === 0))) { continue; }

            if (! text) {
                title = titleFormat ? titleFormat(d[i].x) : d[i].x;
                text = "<table class='" + CLASS.tooltip + "'>" + (title || title === 0 ? "<tr><th colspan='2'>" + title + "</th></tr>" : "");
            }

            name = nameFormat(d[i].name);
            value = valueFormat(d[i].value, d[i].ratio, d[i].id, d[i].index);
            bgcolor = levelColor ? levelColor(d[i].value) : color(d[i].id);

            text += "<tr class='" + CLASS.tooltipName + "-" + d[i].id + "'>";
            text += "<td class='name'><span style='background-color:" + bgcolor + "'></span>" + name + "</td>";
            text += "<td class='value'>" + value + "</td>";
            text += "</tr>";
        }
        return text + "</table>";
    })
```

did anyone attempted to do so? developed some function to facilitate the process? have any tips on how to do so correctly? I do not know how to change their code in a way I could use more data or data different than the d value the function gets.

Comment: I did this once, it's pretty easy to do. However, the a new version (3.0) introduces a modular architecture, so you can override that function and change the content without manipulating the actual source code.

Answer (score 48):

If you use the function getTooltipContent from https://github.com/masayuki0812/c3/blob/master/src/tooltip.js#L27 and add it in the chart declaration, in tooltip.contents, you'll have the same tooltip content that the default one.

You can make changes on this code and customize it as you like. One detail, as `CLASS` is not defined in the current scope, but it's part chart object, I substituted `CLASS` for `$$.CLASS`, maybe you don't even need this Object in your code.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
  /*...*/
  tooltip: {
      format: {
        /*...*/
      },
      contents: function (d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) {
          var $$ = this, config = $$.config,
              titleFormat = config.tooltip_format_title || defaultTitleFormat,
              nameFormat = config.tooltip_format_name || function (name) { return name; },
              valueFormat = config.tooltip_format_value || defaultValueFormat,
              text, i, title, value, name, bgcolor;
          for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
              if (! (d[i] && (d[i].value || d[i].value === 0))) { continue; }

              if (! text) {
                  title = titleFormat ? titleFormat(d[i].x) : d[i].x;
                  text = "<table class='" + $$.CLASS.tooltip + "'>" + (title || title === 0 ? "<tr><th colspan='2'>" + title + "</th></tr>" : "");
              }

              name = nameFormat(d[i].name);
              value = valueFormat(d[i].value, d[i].ratio, d[i].id, d[i].index);
              bgcolor = $$.levelColor ? $$.levelColor(d[i].value) : color(d[i].id);

              text += "<tr class='" + $$.CLASS.tooltipName + "-" + d[i].id + "'>";
              text += "<td class='name'><span style='background-color:" + bgcolor + "'></span>" + name + "</td>";
              text += "<td class='value'>" + value + "</td>";
              text += "</tr>";
          }
          return text + "</table>";
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: In nowadays (2019), no news? No "plug and play change layout", for example if I need only to add my name in the top of the  tooltip.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to control tooltip render and use default rendering depending on data value you can use something like this:

```
tooltip: {
    contents: function (d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) {
        if (d[1].value > 0) {
            // Use default rendering
            return this.getTooltipContent(d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color);
        } else {
            return '<div>Show what you want</div>';
        }
    },
    format: {
        /**/
    }
}
```

Comment: How to modify by D3 the `this.getTooltipContent()` value? For example to change the content of the first TR tag. I need elegant change from   `<table class='c3-tooltip'><tr><th colspan='2'>default string</th></tr>...</table>` to `<table class='c3-tooltip'><tr><th colspan='2'>MY string</th></tr>...</table>`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case i had to add the day for the date value(x axis) in tool tip. Finally i came came up with the below solution

References for js and css

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.css

```js
function toDate(dateStr)
{
    var numbers = dateStr.match(/\d+/g);
    return new Date(numbers[0], numbers[1]-1, numbers[2]);
}
function GetMonthFromString(month)
{
    var months = {'Jan' : '01','Feb' : '02','Mar':'03','Apr':'04',
    'May':'05','Jun':'06','Jul':'07','Aug':'08','Sep':'09',
    'Oct':'10','Nov':'11','Dec':'12'};
    return months[month];
}
function GetFullDayName(formatteddate)
{
    var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0] = "Sunday";
    weekday[1] = "Monday";
    weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
    weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
    weekday[4] = "Thursday";
    weekday[5] = "Friday";
    weekday[6] = "Saturday";
    var dayofdate = weekday[formatteddate.getDay()];
    return dayofdate;
}

//Chart Data for x-axis, OnHours and AvgHours
function CollectChartData()
{
    var xData = new Array();
    var onHoursData = new Array();
    var averageHoursData = new Array();
    var instanceOccuringDatesArray =  ["2017-04-20","2017-04-21","2017-04-22","2017-04-23","2017-04-24","2017-04-25","2017-04-26","2017-04-27","2017-04-28","2017-04-29","2017-04-30","2017-05-01","2017-05-02","2017-05-03","2017-05-04","2017-05-05","2017-05-06","2017-05-07","2017-05-08","2017-05-09","2017-05-10","2017-05-11","2017-05-12","2017-05-13","2017-05-14","2017-05-15","2017-05-16","2017-05-17","2017-05-18","2017-05-19","2017-05-20"];
        var engineOnHoursArray =  ["4.01","14.38","0.10","0.12","0.01","0.24","0.03","6.56","0.15","0.00","1.15","0.00","1.21","2.06","8.55","1.41","0.03","1.42","0.00","3.35","0.02","3.44","0.05","5.41","4.06","0.02","0.04","7.26","1.02","5.09","0.00"];
        var avgUtilizationArray =  ["2.29","2.29","2.29","2.29","2.29","2.29","2.29","2.29","2.29","2.29","2.29","2.29","2.29","2.29","2.29","2.29","2.29","2.29","2.29","2.29","2.29","2.29","2.29","2.29","2.29","2.29","2.29","2.29","2.29","2.29","2.29"];
        xData.push('x');
        onHoursData.push('OnHours');
        averageHoursData.push('Project Average');
        for(var index=0;index<instanceOccuringDatesArray.length;index++)
        {
            xData.push(instanceOccuringDatesArray[index]);
        }
        for(var index=0;index<engineOnHoursArray.length;index++)
        {
            onHoursData.push(engineOnHoursArray[index]);
        }
        for(var index=0;index<avgUtilizationArray.length;index++)
        {
            averageHoursData.push(avgUtilizationArray[index]);
        }
        var Data = [xData, onHoursData, averageHoursData];
        return Data;
    }


function tooltip_contents(d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) {
    var $$ = this, config = $$.config, CLASS = $$.CLASS,
        titleFormat = config.tooltip_format_title || defaultTitleFormat,
        nameFormat = config.tooltip_format_name || function (name) { return name; },
        valueFormat = config.tooltip_format_value || defaultValueFormat,
        text, i, title, value, name, bgcolor;

    // You can access all of data like this:
    //$$.data.targets;

    for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
        if (! text) {
                title = titleFormat ? titleFormat(d[i].x) : d[i].x;
                var arr = title.split(" ");                
                var datestr = new Date().getFullYear().toString() + "-"+ GetMonthFromString(arr[1]) + "-"+ arr[0];                  
               var formatteddate = toDate(datestr);                   
               var dayname = GetFullDayName(formatteddate);
               title = title + " (" + dayname + ")";
                text = "<table class='" + $$.CLASS.tooltip + "'>" + (title || title === 0 ? "<tr><th colspan='2'>" + title + "</th></tr>" : "");
            }

        name = nameFormat(d[i].name);
        var initialvalue = valueFormat(d[i].value, d[i].ratio, d[i].id, d[i].index);
        if (initialvalue.toString().indexOf('.') > -1)
        {
            var arrval = initialvalue.toString().split(".");
            value = arrval[0] + "h " + arrval[1] + "m";
        }
        else
        {
            value = initialvalue + "h " + "00m";
        }
        bgcolor = $$.levelColor ? $$.levelColor(d[i].value) : color(d[i].id);

        text += "<tr class='" + CLASS.tooltipName + "-" + d[i].id + "'>";
        text += "<td class='name'><span style='background-color:" + bgcolor + "'></span>" + name + "</td>";
        text += "<td class='value'>" + value + "</td>";
        text += "</tr>";
    }
    return text + "</table>";   
}
$(document).ready(function () {
     var Data = CollectChartData();
    var chart = c3.generate({
        data: {
                x: 'x',
                columns: Data
            },
            axis: {
                x: {
                    type: 'timeseries',
                    tick: {
                        rotate: 75,
                        //format: '%d-%m-%Y'
                        format: '%d %b'
                    }
                },
                y : {
                    tick : {
                        format: function (y) {
                            if (y < 0) {
                            }
                            return y;
                        }
                    },
                    min : 0,
                    padding : {
                        bottom : 0
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                contents: tooltip_contents
            }
    });
});
```

```html
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>    
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.js"></script>
   <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When we have a stacked bar chart and we would like to show "Total" in the tooltip (but not in the chart as a bar/stack) this can come handy.

C3 charts use a array to store the data for tooltips and before the tooltips are displayed we are adding totals (or anyother data as per our requirement). By doing this though the totals is not available as a stack it is shown in the tooltip.

```
function key_for_sum(arr) {
    return arr.value; //value is the key
};

function sum(prev, next) {
    return prev + next;
}

var totals_object = {};
totals_object.x = d[0]['x'];
totals_object.value = d.map(key_for_sum).reduce(sum);
totals_object.name = 'total';
totals_object.index = d[0]['index'];
totals_object.id = 'total';
d.push(totals_object);
```

Above code has been added to ensure that total is available in

> C3.js Stacked Bar chart's tooltip

```
var chart = c3.generate({
            /*...*/
            tooltip: {
                format: {
                    /*...*/
                },
                contents: function (d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) {

                    function key_for_sum(arr) {
                        return arr.value; //value is the key
                    }

                    function sum(prev, next) {
                        return prev + next;
                    }

                    var totals_object = {};
                    totals_object.x = d[0]['x'];
                    totals_object.value = d.map(key_for_sum).reduce(sum);// sum func
                    totals_object.name = 'total';//total will be shown in tooltip
                    totals_object.index = d[0]['index'];
                    totals_object.id = 'total';//c3 will use this
                    d.push(totals_object);

                    var $$ = this,
                        config = $$.config,
                        titleFormat = config.tooltip_format_title || defaultTitleFormat,
                        nameFormat = config.tooltip_format_name || function (name) {
                            return name;
                        },
                        valueFormat = config.tooltip_format_value || defaultValueFormat,
                        text, i, title, value, name, bgcolor;
                    for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
                        if (!(d[i] && (d[i].value || d[i].value === 0))) {
                            continue;
                        }


                        if (!text) {
                            title = titleFormat ? titleFormat(d[i].x) : d[i].x;
                            text = "<table class='" + $$.CLASS.tooltip + "'>" + (title || title === 0 ? "<tr><th colspan='2'>" + title + "</th></tr>" : "");
                        }

                        name = nameFormat(d[i].name);
                        value = valueFormat(d[i].value, d[i].ratio, d[i].id, d[i].index);
                        bgcolor = $$.levelColor ? $$.levelColor(d[i].value) : color(d[i].id);
                        text += "<tr class='" + $$.CLASS.tooltipName + "-" + d[i].id + "'>";
                        text += "<td class='name'><span style='background-color:" + bgcolor + "'></span>" + name + "</td>";
                        text += "<td class='value'>" + value + "</td>";
                        text += "</tr>";
                    }
                    return text + "</table>";
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding additional content or non-numerical data into the chart tooltips can be done.

This builds on  [@supita's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2668296/) excellent answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25750639/1003746.

Its possible to insert additional metadata about each line into the classes parameter when generating/updating the chart. These can then be added as rows to the tooltip.

This doesn't seem to affect the chart - unless you are using the data.classes feature.

```
data: {
  classes: {
    data1: [{prop1: 10, prop2: 20}, {prop1: 30, prop2: 40}],
    data2: [{prop1: 50, prop2: 60}'{prop1: 70, prop2: 80}]
  }
}
```

To pick up the metadata in the config.

```
      tooltip: {
        contents: function (d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) {
           const $$ = this;
           const config = $$.config;
           const meta = config.data_classes;
           ...
           for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
               if (! (d[i] && (d[i].value || d[i].value === 0))) { continue; }
               if (! text) {
                       ...
                }
               const line = d[0].id;
               const properties = meta.classes[line];
               const property = properties? properties[i] : null;
```

Then add the following rows to the table to show the new properties.

```
               if (property ) {
                 text += "<tr class='" + $$.CLASS.tooltipName + "-" + d[i].id + "'>";
                 text += "<td class='name'><span style='background-color:" + bgcolor + "'></span>PROP1</td>";
                 text += "<td class='name'><span style='background-color:" + bgcolor + "'></span>" + property.prop1 + "</td>";
                 text += "</tr>";
                 text += "<tr class='" + $$.CLASS.tooltipName + "-" + d[i].id + "'>";
                 text += "<td class='name'><span style='background-color:" + bgcolor + "'></span>PROP2</td>";
                 text += "<td class='name'><span style='background-color:" + bgcolor + "'></span>" +
                         property.prop2+ " cm/s</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If anybody cares, here is a **ClojureScript version** of the above algorithm (e.g. [supita's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25750639/127465)), slightly simplified (without support for config). (This is probably nothing the OP asked for, but as of now there are so few resources on the net on this topic that most people might wind up here.)

```
:tooltip {
  :contents
    (fn [d default-title-format default-value-format color]
      (this-as this
        (let [this-CLASS         (js->clj (.-CLASS this) :keywordize-keys true)
              tooltip-name-class (:tooltipName this-CLASS)
              rows               (js->clj d :keywordize-keys true)
              title-row (->> (first rows) (#(str "<table class='" (:tooltip this-CLASS) 
                                                 "'><tr><th colspan='2'>" 
                                                 (default-title-format (:x %)) "</th></tr>")))
              data-rows (->> rows
                             (map #(str "<tr class='" tooltip-name-class "--" (:id %) "'>"
                                        "<td class='name'><span style='background-color:" 
                                        (color (:id %)) "'></span>" (:name %) "</td>"
                                        "<td class='value'>" (default-value-format (:value %)) "</td>"
                                        "</tr>")))]
              (str title-row (string/join data-rows) "</table>"))))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about changing the content of the tooltip in c3js.

The tooltip has 3 variables

```
+----------------+
|      title     |
+----------------+
|  name  | value |
+----------------+
```

Plus, you want to add 'name' from an additional variable, other than those used in 'column'.

```
tooltip: {
        format: {
          title(x, index) { return ''; },
          name(name, ratio, id, index) { return lst[index + 1]; },
          value(value, ratio, id, index) { return value; }
        }
      },
```

> this worked for me, feel free to play around with the arguments, to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a problem which is related tooltip position and style for c3 before. in order to arrange tooltip in c3 freely, my suggestion is manipulating tooltip with d3.

```
// internal = chart.internal()

const mousePos = d3.mouse(internal.svg.node()); // find mouse position
const clientX = mousePos[0]; //for x
const clientY = mousePos[1]; //for y
const tooltip = d3.select("#tooltip"); //select tooltip div (apply your style)
tooltip.style("display", "initial");  //show tooltip
tooltip.style("left", clientX - mouseOffSet.X + "px"); // set position
tooltip.style("top", clientY - mouseOffSet.Y + "px");  // set position
tooltip.html("<span>" + content + "</span>");   

// you can arrange all content and style whatever you want





   

 <div
      id="tooltip"
      className="your-style"
      style={{ display: "none", position: "absolute" }}
    />





Good luck!!
```