# C3js Stacked Bar Chart with a hidden bar

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

**Scenario:** I need to show a bar chart about payment details, how much the customers paid for a product using Card, Cheque or Cash. And also need to display the total value in a stacked bar chart.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['Cash', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['Card', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50],
            ['Total', 160,300,240,600,300,300]
        ],
        groups:[['Cash','Card']],
        type: 'bar'
    }
});
```

**Output:**

[image]

I need to show the Total value but not the bar and the legend. How can do this? Any advice would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the total dataset, you can alter the tooltip contents to calculate it on the fly (adapting the technique found in the answer here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/36789099/368214)

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['Cash', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['Card', 130, 100, 140, 200, 150, 50],
        ],
        groups:[['Cash','Card']],
        type: 'bar'
    }, 
    tooltip : {
        contents: function (d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) {
            var total = d.reduce (function(subTotal,b) { return subTotal + b.value; }, 0);
            d.push ({value: total, id: "Total", name: "Total", x:d[0].x , index:d[0].index});
            return this.getTooltipContent(d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color);
        }
    }
});
```

The total value is calculated using .reduce to sum all the other values at that point. Then make a new data point for the tooltip called 'Total' using that value and pass it to the default renderer for drawing (this.getTooltipContent)

http://jsfiddle.net/vz1rwvwn/